# Getting "AccessDenied: Access Denied" inside lambda when getting an object from s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

### Update 2

I've tried changing our custom policy to allow access to the particular bucket that's giving the `AccessDenied` error, without any luck. Imagine that `bucket1` is a bucket that the lambda normally accesses, and `bucket2` is the bucket that's throwing `AccessDenied` when the lambda accesses it. I've changed the `Resource` block from

```
{
        ...
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::us-east-1-bucket1/*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
        ...
```

to

```
{
        ...
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::us-east-1-bucket1/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::us-east-1-bucket2/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
        ...
```

I'm still getting the `AccessDenied` error.

---

### Update

Per @Caldazar's comment about IAM users vs roles, the lambda's execution role has 3 policies:

- the AWS managed `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSXRayDaemonWriteAccess`, specifically:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "xray:PutTraceSegments",
                "xray:PutTelemetryRecords",
                "xray:GetSamplingRules",
                "xray:GetSamplingTargets",
                "xray:GetSamplingStatisticSummaries"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

- the AWS managed `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole`, specifically:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

- our custom policy, specifically:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:*:log-group:/aws/lambda/*:*:*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::us-east-1-bucket1/*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

In lambda@edge I have an `origin-response` response lambda that is trying to pull an object out of s3 to be used as the response. However I'm getting this `AccessDenied` error when I try to list the contents of the bucket using a particular prefix. This is my code:

```js
const getVidS3 = (s3, bucketName, fileName) =>
    new Promise((res, rej) => {
        const start = Date.now();
        s3.listObjects(
            {
                Bucket: bucketName,
                Delimiter: '/',
                Prefix: `${fileName}/`,
                MaxKeys: 1,
            },
            function (err, data) {
                console.log(
                    '================ milliseconds to list objects:',
                    Date.now() - start
                );
                if (err) return rej(err);
                if (!Array.isArray(data.Contents) || data.Contents.length < 1) {
                    return rej('original raw video not found');
                }
                console.log('============= s3 objects:', data);
                const rawVidFileKey = data.Contents[0].Key;
                s3.getObject(
                    {
                        Bucket: bucketName,
                        Key: rawVidFileKey,
                    },
                    (err, data) => {
                        console.log(
                            '================ milliseconds to get video object:',
                            Date.now() - start
                        );
                        if (err) {
                            return rej(err);
                        }

                        const contentType = data.ContentType;
                        const video = data.Body;
                        console.log('=============== S3 video data', data);
                        return res({ video, contentType });
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    });
```

The error is from `listObjects`. I've gone over [this set of suggestions](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/) but I'm not sure I took the right steps because I used the IAM user that I use to access the dashboard, which may have higher permissions than the one the lambda uses. More so, I recreated this `getVidS3` function locally using my admin credentials and it works, so I think I need help determining how to give the lambda the appropriate permissions. I didn't create the system and I'm not very proficient with aws, so bear with me if this feels incomplete. What/where else can I check to see why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Lambda function doesn't use IAM user, but IAM Role. Can you share the role's permission policy? It looks like that is the problem

Comment: @Caldazar I've updated the question to include the policies. In the process I also noticed that the custom policy grants s3 access for a  different s3 bucket, not the one I'm trying to access, so maybe that's it. I'll check and give feedback. If anything else jumps out about the policies please let me know.

Comment: @Caldazar adding the bucket to the policy didn't resolve the problem. What else do you think I can try/check? I've updated the question again to show how I tried to change the policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your policy. The policy allows `GET` of the objects, but not `List`. You're missing the `ListBucket` action on the bucket itself.

You need to change this:

```
{
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::us-east-1-bucket1/*",
        "Effect": "Allow"
    }
```

To this:

```
{
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": [
             "arn:aws:s3:::us-east-1-bucket1/*",
             "arn:aws:s3:::us-east-1-bucket1"
         ]
        "Effect": "Allow"
    }
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks. There's a new problem, i posted about it here https://stackoverflow.com/q/71092918/7987987. I'd appreciate if you can take a look and offer your thoughts. :)