# 503 error from cloudfront cdn when loading video from s3 using lambda

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I'm getting an error when fetching videos from s3 as part of the `origin-response` trigger. This is my code:

```js
const getVidS3 = (s3, bucketName, fileName) =>
    new Promise((res, rej) => {
        const start = Date.now();
        s3.listObjects(
            {
                Bucket: bucketName,
                Delimiter: '/',
                Prefix: `${fileName}/`,
                MaxKeys: 1,
            },
            function (err, data) {
                console.log(
                    '================ milliseconds to list objects:',
                    Date.now() - start
                );
                if (err) return rej(err);
                if (!Array.isArray(data.Contents) || data.Contents.length < 1) {
                    return rej('original raw video not found');
                }
                console.log('============= s3 objects:', data);
                const rawVidFileKey = data.Contents[0].Key;
                s3.getObject(
                    {
                        Bucket: bucketName,
                        Key: rawVidFileKey,
                    },
                    (err, data) => {
                        console.log(
                            '================ milliseconds to get video object:',
                            Date.now() - start
                        );
                        if (err) {
                            return rej(err);
                        }

                        const contentType = data.ContentType;
                        const video = data.Body;
                        console.log('=============== S3 video data', data);
                        return res({ video, contentType });
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    });
                const videoFile = await getVidS3(fileName);
                response.status = 200;
                response.headers['Content-Type'] = [
                    { key: 'Content-Type', value: videoFile.contentType },
                ];
                response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = [
                    { key: 'Content-Disposition', value: 'inline' },
                ];

                response.headers['Cache-Control'] = [
                    { key: 'Cache-Control', value: 'public,max-age=1' },
                ];
                response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = [
                    {
                        key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
                        value: 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE',
                    },
                ];
                response.statusDescription = 'OK';
                response.body = videoFile.video;
```

From this article it seems that binary files should be sent as base64 encoded strings, so I tried changing the last line of code to

```js
                const base64Vid = videoFile.video.toString('base64');
                response.body = base64Vid;
                response.bodyEncoding = 'base64';
```

But the problem hasn't gone away. I've confirmed that the video is getting fetched from s3, so it seems that I'm setting the body incorrectly. This is the error from the lambda: `ERROR Validation error: The Lambda function returned an invalid json output, json is not parsable.`

What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you're getting videos, the probable issue is that your response payload is too large.

You can check other limitations in the official [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html) but for the request and response payload, the max allowed size is 6 MB. I assume you have a video that is bigger than 6 MB.

Comment: The size of one such video is actually 873.9 KB in this case. But it had that problem. Do you have an idea what else the issue could be?